# Bug in XAML (Windows Univeral)?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

**(New info below)**

To reproduce:

In a default Universal App - Using the following code (An `Image` inside a `ScrollViewer`) - when disabling vertical scrolling and beginning to scroll (horizontally) using the mouse wheel - the `ScrollViewer` doesn't maintain its vertical offset.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" >Disable Vertical Scrolling</Button>
    <Button Name="button2" Click="button2_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0,50,0,0" >Enable Vertical Scrolling</Button>
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Width="100" Height="100" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <Image Stretch="None" Source="Assets/Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png"></Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
}
```

Note: This doesn’t happen in all cases. It does in the following:

1. **Drag** the vertical scrollbar, and then scroll **using the mouse
   wheel**.
2. Click to disable vertical scrolling.
3. Scroll (horizontally) **using the wheel**.

Instead of the Image ***only*** moving horizontally - It also centers vertically.

Is this really a bug, or do I have a mistake in my code? If it is - Any workaround? (We can't derive from `ScrollViewer` because it's `sealed`.)

**New Info**

If one waits for the scrollbars to disappear after disabling the vertical scrolling - the vertical offset ***is*** maintained. Perhaps it only saves the offset when they disappear. I still can't find a workaround, though.